# Curse words and dictionary

Tags: sms, autocorrect, dictionary

This behaviour I have observed with the Polish dictionary, but I'm assuming that it applies to other languages similarly.

I've noticed that the dictionary in Windows phone seems to ignore curse words. If I type them in, it never suggests them, even though the spellchecker doesn't mark them as typos (hence I can't add them to the dictionary). Is there any way to change this? I don't curse that much, but it's a nuisance nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wptext/how-do-i-add-curse-words-to-my-keyboard-dictionary/49eb41c4-d761-4523-9471-e36749729fbd) and [WPCentral forum](http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8/223430-cant-add-vulgar-words-profanity-dictionary-print.html) both say that adding foul language to the dictionary is not currently possible.

Comment: That sucks. Thanks for the reply, anyway. For some reason I couldn't find those with Google.

Comment: Yeah, there is a uservoice feature request that you can vote up. http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2556045-add-word-to-text-dictionary-auto-predict-

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use accented letters where there should be any. For example, replacing the u in F*ck with ū results in a word which can be added to the dictionary and will happily be suggested by the keyboard.